# Как поменять цвет текста при выводе в консоль?

Tags: python

Два примера:

```
print('Как поменять цвет?')

print('Как поменять цвет одного слова?')
```

Как поменять цвет всего текста или его части при выводе в консоль?

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать `colorama`:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back
colorama.init()
print(Back.BLUE + Fore.GREEN + "text")
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать ansi

```
print('\033[96mКак поменять цвет?\033[0m')
print('Как поменять цвет ' + '\033[96mодного\033[0m' + ' слова?')
```

Comment: Будет работать только под \*nix системами

Comment: не работает...(

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать пакет `termcolor`

```
from termcolor import colored

print(colored('Как поменять цвет?', 'red'))
print('Как поменять цвет '+ colored('одного', 'green') +' слова?')
```

Если без пакета, то будет зависеть от конкретной ОС, так как терминалы разные.

Comment: Не работает...(

Comment: @merkar так установите библиотеку. pip install termcolor

Answer (score 0):

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
start = "\033[1;31m"
end = "\033[0;0m"
print("Hello " + start + "world!" + end)
```